# Why does json_decode return null after utf8_decode

Tags: php, json, utf-8, special-characters

I am have retrieved a string from data base that contains Unicode characters, 
After that I have utf8_decoded them so I can read them clearly,

Then I passed the string to `json_decode` but it return null! 
without utf8_decode the `json_decode` return an array with `Ã©` characters.

Comment: Did you try leaving out the decoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utf8_decode` *converts* a string's encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, a.k.a. Latin-1.
`json_decode` expects, requires and returns UTF-8 encoded strings.
That's why it's obviously not working.

The string you get from the database is apparently UTF-8 encoded, which is good. You *must not* convert it to Latin-1 before you decode the JSON. You *should* also not convert it afterwards, just keep everything in UTF-8. The only problem you have is that you're not correctly instructing your browser to deal with UTF-8. The quick answer is to set a proper HTTP header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

For the longer and more nuanced answer(s), see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).